Razor Pages Form Validation/Creation
My form "Create form" isn't hitting the OnPost method.
I spent quite a few hours trying to get this solved. Though I'm new and I mostly have no clue whats going on. I tried researching it and ended up hoping posting this would get me to answers
I checked that when errorMessage and successMessage aren't empty the message is printed out properly. But I can't seem to make it work the way it's supposed to. The form just resets and I don't see  adifference.
Thank you in advance!
Value.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TaxCalculator.Models
{
    public class Value    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

The ValueDto:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TaxCalculator.Models
{
    public class ValueDto
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

The Create.cshtml:
@page
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal
@model TaxCalculator.Pages.Admin.Products.CreateModel
@{
}

<div class=" row">
    <div class=" col-md-8 mx-auto rounded border p-3">
        <h2 class=" text-center mb-5">New Value</h2>

        @if (Model.errorMessage.Length > 0)
        {
            <div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                <strong>@Model.errorMessage</strong>
                <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
            </div>
        }
        else if (Model.successMessage.Length > 0)
        {
            <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'>
                <strong>@Model.successMessage</strong>
                <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
            </div>
        }
        <form method=" post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label class=" col-sm-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class=" col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="ValueDto.Name"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ValueDto.Name" class=" text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="offset-sm-4 col-sm-4 d-grid">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 d-grid">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/Admin/Products/Index" role="button">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

This is the Create.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using TaxCalculator.Models;
using TaxCalculator.Services;

namespace TaxCalculator.Pages.Admin.Values
{
      public class CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext context) : PageModel
      {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context = context;

        [BindProperty]
        public ValueDto ValueDto { get; set; } = new ValueDto();

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public string errorMessage = "";
        public string successMessage = "";

        public void OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                errorMessage = "Please provide all the required fields";
                return;
            }

            var credit = new Credit
            {
                Name = ValueDto.Name,
            };

            context.Values.Add(credit);
            context.SaveChanges();

            //clear the form
            ValueDto.Name = "";

            ModelState.Clear();

            successMessage = "Credit created successfully";

            Response.Redirect("/Admin/Products/Index");
        } 
    }
}


Your form method contains space. Can you remove the space and see it works? method="post". Asie, you mentioned that the OnPost method is not hit, as your errorMessage and successMessage are initialized with empty string. So it doesn't make sense that you say those variables are printed out but the OnPost is not hit.

Hi @Emin, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.


Checked that when errorMessage and successMessage aren't empty the
message is printed out properly. But I can't seem to make it work the
way it's supposed to. The form just resets and I don't see
adifference.

Well your issue is pretty obvious the way you are trying to get the error or success message that would always be empty.
Becuase, else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SuccessMessage)) block not executing after the post request is likely due to the Response.Redirect call in the OnPost method.
You should know, when Response.Redirect is called, it initiates a new request to the specified URL, which causes the current page state to be lost, including the SuccessMessage.
Therefore, you should change your current implementation if you want to keep the SuccessMessage and ErrorMessage value even after redirection . In order to fix that issue, use tempData in following manner which will keep your application state with value:
Modify Model:
 [TempData]
 public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

 [TempData]
 public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }

Refactor OnPost Method:
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Please provide all the required fields";
        return Page();
    }

    var value = new Value
    {
        Name = ValueDto.Name,
    };

   _context.Values.Add(value);
   _context.SaveChanges();

    // Clear the form
    ValueDto.Name = "";

    ModelState.Clear();

    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Value created successfully";

    return RedirectToPage("/Admin/Products/Index");
}

Note: Change the return type from void to IActionResult and Use RedirectToPage instead of Response.Redirect
Output:





Note: You could use other way to manage your application state but considering your scenario TempData will resolve your issue.
